# Cant fix "The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine." error

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, ms-office

I am trying to add a database to my vb.net application for the user to write to. When I test the connection I get the following message: "The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine." I have looked on other threads and they say to download a database engine. I have attempted to install 32 and 64 bit but I still can't get it sorted. I am using Windows 10 with Visual Studio 2019 and MS Office 2010. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Study the last comment [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/answers/answers/435214/view.html?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-5002361) from Albert.

Comment: You can install the x86 version of `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` and the x64 version of `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0` (**16**) (or the other way around). You didn't say what is the bitness of your application and if you used Visual Studio tools to build and handle your source of data.  -- If you don't use any tools provided by Visual Studio, you can target AnyCPU (provided that you have deselected `Prefer 32-bit`) and use any of those providers.  The machines where you install your app must have one of the two installed. You can use an Installer and set the prerequisites.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. When you say the bitness of my application are you on about the thing in settings where it says prefer 32-bit or something like that? I don't think I used VS tools to build or handle the data. I did change the preferred CPU thing but it didn't do anything. Sorry if I'm not very clear, relatively new to this kind of stuff

Comment: Run somewhere `Console.WriteLine(IntPtr.Size)`, see if it prints 8 or 4. -- Download and install [Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920). Try the x64 version first. -- In `Project->Properties->Compile`, set the Target CPU to AnyCPU and make sure `Prefer 32-bit` is not selected. Rebuild the Solution. Now, try to create a connection using any of the two providers. -- Add the .Net version in use to the question.

Comment: So it came out with 8. I downloaded and installed the x64 version and did as you said but still got the same outcome. When I tried to install the x86 version I got an error saying it couldn;t install because I already had x64 installed. After I uninstalled the x64 version I retried the x86 but I still get the same error saying I have 64 bit office products installed. On that last comment from Albert, are they saying that it should still work but I just can't test the connection? I'm really confused lol

Comment: Since your app runs as a 64bit process and you have the x64 version of Office, you should be able to use the `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` provider without issues, and also the `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0` provider. Did you set the Target to `AnyCPU` (both in Debug and Release)? -- If you still have some exception, post your code and enough context to understand what's going on in your app.

Comment: Oh okay I get what you're saying. Yes the target is AnyCPU in Project>Properties>Compile and the prefer 32-bit checkbox is unticked. Is there another place I have to select or deselect something for it to be both in debug and release? I haven't written any code yet, just msgbox(IntPtr.Size) when form1 loads.

Comment: A first debugging step that I would recommend is to dump a list of OleDB providers and make sure that it's actually set up correctly.  In order to do this, you'll need to iterate over every key under CLSID and check for a dword value named "OLEDB_SERVICES"; if that value exists, the name of the provider is the default value of the key.  32-bit is in HKCR/Wow6432Node/CLSID, 64-bit is in HKCR/CLSID.  (This could be done fairly easily in a .NET program, or you could script it, I have a vbs file for doing it for both 32-bit and 64-bit.)

Comment: If you haven't written any code, what are you testing now?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, I clicked the test connection button in the firm that appears when I try to add the database.

Comment: What *connection Button*? What *Form that appears*? No Forms appear when you connect to a database. Because you explicitly said that you're not using any Tool provided by Visual Studio. Thus, there's nothing to *add*. You just define the connect string and open a new `OleDbConnection`. In code. -- If you're trying to do something else, describe it **in the body of the question**. If you have code, add it **to the question**.

Comment: Hi @Jimi, I have a screenshot of the form here: https://imgur.com/a/5PFCDmS. Would this be an example of using a tool from VS? If so I didn't know.

Comment: That stuff is really useless. You need to create and open an `OleDbConnection` **in code**.

Comment: Oh okay, this is how a few tutorials say to do it though. I'll have a look online. Would I still get the same error about not being registered on the local machine?